# How to interpret this COBOL(?) record layout to create a MySQL TABLE?

Tags: mysql, cobol

I have this record layout for a field positional .txt database to convert into a MySQL TABLE. There is a column in the record layout titled "PICTURE" I'm not certain what it's describing for the data types. This looks vaguely familiar, perhaps it's a COBOL record layout method?

Here are some examples and my assumptions:

9(4) I'm guessing "9" means a number and "(4)" means 4 digits.

"X" is a character?

9(5)V9(4) - I don't know.
S9(7)V99 - I don't know.

Here is a link to the actual record layout I'm referring to:
http://www.state.nj.us/treasury/taxation/lpt/MODIV-Counties/2013/MODIVLayout.pdf

I someone can explain these or a guide to them, that would be most helpful. I don't get the purpose of the FILLER field coming from MySQL. Thanks!

Comment: From the lengths of the fields with decimals (and the other numerics) you have no "packed-decimal" fields. You have one "signed" field (see Bruce's answer). If you data is being transferred from a Mainframe, which uses EBCDIC, that field will cause you a problem. Ask for it to be defined with a "separate sign" which will get you an actual + or - and plain unadulterated numeric digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My interpretation, I hope it helps you:

- **9(4)**: as you said a number with 4 digits (see the length column in your screen)
- **X(4)**: a string with length of 4 (see the length column in your screen)
- **999**: a number with 3 digits
- **XXX**: a string with the length of 3
- **9(5)V9(4)**: a decimal number with 5 digits before decimal point and 4 after decimal places (no "." will be written to save diskspace
  [see length of 9])
- **S9(7)V99**: I guess a procentual value with 7 digits before decimal point and 2 after it (no % sign)

You can ignore all groups, because there could not be mapped to MySql (ORDBMS only [OOP])

I hope i could help you a bit... ;-)

Comment: You should update your answer for the S9(7)V99. COBOL itself doesn't have "strings" the way the term is used elsewhere. Neither the X(4) nor the other fields have anything as a "field terminator". It is four bytes long, no matter what it contains. "Short" data in the field will typically be "padded" with space. The point of not have the "." in a number is *not* to save disk-space. It is necessary not to have it if doing calculations.

Comment: In this particular case "you can ignore all groups". For instance, for a date containing DD MM and YYYY you'd want them as a "date" field in the database.

Answer (score 3):

Following from 5im, in cobol, **S9(7)V99** the sign is normally represented as an **over type** of the lowest order digit. You can see this in the s9(7)V99 fields, they are all 9 bytes long with no space allocated for the sign.

The actual sign character used will depend on wether it is an source computer uses **ascii** (i.e. Unix) or **Ebcidic** (ie IBM).

so -1.21 becomes

- **Mainframe** 00000012J
- **Ascii**     00000012q

so -1.22 becomes

- **Mainframe** 00000012K
- **Ascii**     00000012r

also positive numbers 1.20 can be represented as follows

- **Mainframe** 00000012{
- **Ascii**     00000012@

and +1.21 can be represented as 00000012A

I would suggest clarify the forat of the s9(7)V99 fields.
Look up zoned decimal definition

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from 5im's answer.

FILLER means empty space.  You don't have to put FILLER fields in a database.  FILLER fields are either fields that are no longer required, or empty spaces left in the record layout so new information could be added without changing the record length.

The decimal numbers like 9(5)V9(4) and S9(7)V99 can be stored in DECIMAL columns.